# What would be a normal voltage in the voltage feedback pin of a PWM controller?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm

Several SMPS use a topology that employs an optocoupler to close the control loop for the PWM controller that drives the primary of the ferrite transformer.

However, I'm not sure and I can't find information of what should be the typical voltage in the feedback pin of these controllers.

The feedback pin, also called COMP in some controllers, is grounded by the optocoupler when it's conducing, but I don't see any pull up resistor in them (on the outside).

And I have this TV PSU (A 715G6677) which is not functioning and have a wildly oscillating DC voltage everywhere where it should have a stable 12 V in the "standby" circuit.

It's oscillating form 9 to 16 V while open, and falls to 4 to 7 volts if I put a 200 ohm resistor on the output.

This "standby" circuit also powers the TV motherboard, so it has a reasonable power, just not if compared to the circuit that powers the LEDs.

It uses a LD5532 controller and this is the typical application shown in its datasheet:

[image]

On my PSU, the circuit is a bit different but has the same basic topology, just a bit more convoluted than this one.

The points where I should read 12 V that I mentioned before would be equivalent to the positive of the DC output of this scheme here.

The voltage on the VCC pin of the LD5532 (which is fed by a separate winding) is also oscillating wildly, the transformer is not being properly driven and it isn't producing enough voltage (on that separate winding) to power the chip, it's seemingly being powered only by that resistor that comes from the AC mains.

And, what's more, the voltage on the COMP pin is steady at zero like it was grounded.

I removed the optocoupler and tested it, it seems to be operating normally.

I don't know if this reading is normal and I can't find any reference for what voltage should be seen in there, and It seems weird to me that it's steady at zero while the output is oscillating wildly.

Is this normal or should there be something wrong with the controller?

If you want to check it, [here's](https://www.electronica-pt.com/esquema/func-download/33736/chk,2b075fcd21c1b6a1a51bbb7e8d825471/no_html,1/) the schematics for my PSU, check on the A03 circuit (standby). The AC Input and PFC are working perfectly as far as I could test.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Here https://cdn.datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/L/D/5/LD5532-LeadtrendTechnology.pdf

Comment: I guess it ought to be between 1.65 Burst Mode and 2V Green mode. Burst is hysteresis +/-100mV

Comment: Check capacitor C9034. When this cap fails, the psu will ‘tick’. Parallel or substitute another cap of similar rating/value and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Kartman you mean C9304?

Comment: Ha! Dyslexia rules KO. Sorry, yes i did mean C9304. C9305 might be suspect as well.

Comment: @Kartman It is working normally. And so is diode D9302. 

Although that, for some reason, the voltage on this capacitor (which is in the anode side of the D9393 diode) is stable at 2.5 V, doesn't oscillate. Meanwhile, the voltage on the capacitors on the cathode side of D9393 is oscillating in pretty much higher values.

Comment: That tells me the psu is trying to wake up, but is shutting down. Have you checked for shorts on the outputs?

Comment: Check C9302 for shorts, D9301,R9305 and R9306. The snubber capacitor failing has caught  me out before. Last TV i fixed the cap went short and took out the fet, controller and a couple of other bits. Finding the pwm controller was a challenge.

Comment: @Kartman all of them are fine. But now I found another problem, actually a repetition of the first problem I found. Diode 9311 was shorted for some reason, completely shorted. Then I replaced it and then things started to behave the way I described here. So today I took a 18 V DC and a 5 V DC power supply and fed them to the VCC1 voltage (which powers the PWM controller) and the PS_ON pin, which gives the signal to turn it on. When I did that it started working for some time, I had 12 V on 12VS and it wasn't oscillating. And then the same diode (D9311) shorted once again. Any ideas?

Comment: Your link to the schematic has failed :(

Comment: @Kartman seems like they deleted it from yesterday to today. I reuploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFFFK875TbX5dwTEC2U4gvOVC8pcl-ZJ

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unanswerable in its current form: "read the datasheet" is essentially the answer requested, but is too "low quality" to get upvoted (or evade deletion).

Answer (score 0):

Each PWM controller is different.

There's no standard input voltage for the COMP pin.

It's usually in the 1-4 V range.

Comment: But anyway it's something I can measure, right? Cause my voltmeter is indicating 0 V. Nothing, not even a fraction.

Comment: Yes, I measured it many times in my AC/DC projects. I used a scope.